# Python Boto3 upload image from url to AWS S3 bucket: ValueError('Filename must be a string')

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get an image from a url and upload that image to my AWS S3 bucket. I am currectly getting a `ValueError('Filename must be a string')` error.

**code:**

```py
ACCESS_KEY = ''
SECRET_KEY = ''

def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False

url = "https://product-images.tcgplayer.com/{}.jpg".format(sealed_product['identifiers'].get('tcgplayerProductId'))
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    with open('temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        uploaded = upload_to_aws(f, 'cardcompanion-s3-bucket', "{}.jpg".format(sealed_product['identifiers'].get('tcgplayerProductId')))
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\card_companion_v2\card_companion_310_venv\lib\site-packages\background_task\tasks.py", line 43, in bg_runner
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\card_companion_v2\administration\views.py", line 97, in set_update_bg_task
    set_update_magic_sets_sealed_products(set_json, options) if options.get('sealed_products') == 'true' else None
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\card_companion_v2\administration\views.py", line 189, in set_update_magic_sets_sealed_products
    uploaded = upload_to_aws(f, 'cardcompanion-s3-bucket', "{}.jpg".format(sealed_product['identifiers'].get('tcgplayerProductId')))
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\card_companion_v2\administration\views.py", line 174, in upload_to_aws
    s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\card_companion_v2\card_companion_310_venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 130, in upload_file
    return transfer.upload_file(
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\card_companion_v2\card_companion_310_venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py", line 281, in upload_file
    raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string
```

Comment: Besides what @jellycsv said, unless I am missing something or the code snippet is incomplete, you are also missing code to actually download the image and store it in temp.jpg

Answer (score 2):

`s3.upload_file` expects a filename in the first param. You should use `upload_fileobj` instead.